# How do I print the display name?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view with multiple pages. In the Views interface, I can set a display name for each display.

> [image: screenshot]

Is there anyway I can print this name in the view itself, for example adding a *Global Text* field to the views header?

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, the "Global: Result summary" field in Views header gives you a few tokens to get access to some of the view information (e.g. it has a token named `@name -- the human-readable name of the view`  to print the View name).

For fetching the View display name, though, you need to create a custom Views handler to define your own tokens:

- Create a new module. In your `my_module_name.info` file, add the lines :

```
    dependencies[] = views

    files[] = handlers/views_handler_my_custom_handler.inc
```

- In your `my_module.module` file, add a hook_views_data():

```php
    function my_module_views_data() {
        // Definition of your custom handler
        $data['views']['my_module_custom_handler'] = array(
            'title' => t('My custom handler'),
            'help' => t('Custom tokens to access View information'),
            'area' => array(
                'handler' => 'views_handler_my_custom_handler',
            ),
        );
        return $data;
    }
```

- Finally, create the `handlers/views_handler_my_custom_handler.inc` file. The most basic content based on your needs would be something like:

```php
/**
 * @file
 * Definition of views_handler_area.
 */

/**
 * Views area handler to display some configurable result summary.
 *
 * @ingroup views_area_handlers
 */
class views_handler_my_custom_handler extends views_handler_area {

    function option_definition() {
        $options = parent::option_definition();
        $options['content'] = array(
            'default' => 'Displaying view tokens',
            'translatable' => TRUE,
        );
        return $options;
    }

    function options_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
        parent::options_form($form, $form_state);

        $variables = array(
            'items' => array(
                '@display_name -- the name of the View display'
            ),
        );
        $list = theme('item_list', $variables);
        $form['content'] = array(
            '#title' => t('Display'),
            '#type' => 'textarea',
            '#rows' => 3,
            '#default_value' => $this->options['content'],
            '#description' => t('You may use HTML code in this field. The following tokens are supported:') . $list,
        );
    }

    /**
     * Find out the information to render.
     */
    function render($empty = FALSE) {
        $format = $this->options['content'];
        // Replace "@display_name" with view current display value
        $output = filter_xss_admin(str_replace("@display_name", $this->view->current_display, $format));
        return $output;
    }
```

That's it. Your custom views handler should now be available in any View.

I recommend you to have a look at view_handler_area_result.inc file (code for "Global: Result summary" field) in Views module if you wish to extend it to have its tokens available in your custom handler.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to print the name of the View, rather than the display name of the page. E.g. A view is called "Indexes". And in that view, you create multiple pages, each which have a different display name. `@name` prints `Indexes` rather than the display name of the page.

Comment: My bad, you are absolutely right! Basic Views tokens are not enough for what you need.  Please see my edited answer.